# Python unittest counting successful asserts in a test

Tags: python, unit-testing, assert

I wanted to know if there is a builtin way in Python's unittest to count the successful asserts in the current test.
The idea would be to be sure that the current test is actually testing something or that it is doing the right number of asserts.

E.g.:

```
def test_testing_method(self):
    ... Do my test with self.assert... calls ...
    ... Check that this method tested something ...
```

Comment: Are you interested in counting `assert expression` or `self.assertTrue(expression)`?

Comment: All self.assert... calls.

Comment: Monkey-patch self.assertXXX() functions to increase a counter stored as instance variable on the test case.

Comment: I believe you'll have to subclass `TestCase` and override all `assert...` methods:( But may be you could explain (post some code) why you want it this way?

Comment: I think the only solution is subclassing too... I'd like it that way because sometimes the test is not obvious and I am not sure that it is actually testing something (or the full thing).